# Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have written some java code in an adapter in worklight project. when i m trying to call the java method, i am getting an error saying

> "responseID":"6","errors": {Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property downloadFile in object
>   JavaPackage java.classes.FileIOPlugin]. It is not a function, it is
>   \"object\".}

I have followed the procedure exactly stated in the following link. 
[Using Java in Adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/Module_05_5_-_Using_Java_in_Adapters.pdf)

this is my project structure. Is there something wrong with this structure or should i add anything more to this?

[image]

This is how i am trying to call the java non-static method in adapter-impl.js

```
function downloadFile() {
    var fileInstance = new com.worklight.JavaCode.FileIOPlugin();
    return
    {   result: fileInstance.downloadFile();    };
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have identified another possible solution to this.

- Change Java compiler level to 1.6 as well as default JRE to 1.6:

[image: Compiler level]
[image: JRE version]

Comment: I had a similar issue, @christianmenkens response at [this se post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614742/ecma-typeerror-calling-java-class-from-worklight-adapter?rq=1) solved my problem

Comment: you spotted it! also I had to remove the previous "malformed" application from server and rebuild the WAR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package starts with com, e.g. rename it to "com.classes".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. but i have tried that too. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parenthesis when you instantiate your object:

```
var fileInstance = new com.worklight.JavaCode.FileIOPlugin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your .project file and make sure it has the right buildCommand tags in it.

```
<buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.worklight.studio.plugin.WorklightProjectBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Read more at: [ECMA TypeError calling Java class from Worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614742/ecma-typeerror-calling-java-class-from-worklight-adapter/16761874#16761874)