# IBM Worklight 6.1 - "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property <function> in object"

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to run the Java in Worklight Adapters example from the `worklightadapterproject` smaple project, but I am facing an error when trying to invoke a procedure:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property addTwoIntegers in object [JavaPackage com.worklight.customcode.Calculator1]. It is not a function, it is \"object\". (C%3A%5CWorklightLab%5Cworkspace%5CWorklightAdaptersProject%5Cadapters%5CCalculatorAdapter\/CalculatorAdapter-impl.js#9)"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

How do I resolve this?

I tried setting this by using the following configuration which didn't work:

[image: config preferences]
[image: config preferences 2]

Comment: I'm willing to bet money on your war not being built right. Extract it and try to find the class you're trying to create an instance of, and I bet you it won't be there.

Comment: I'm willing to bet money as well, see my answer below. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked before. See the following questions and their solutions.
This is caused by one of two things:

1. By not using [Java compiler level 1.6 and JRE v1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826456/ecma-error-typeerror-cannot-call-property) (probably)
2. Due to [a missing segment in the `.project` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614742/ecma-typeerror-calling-java-class-from-worklight-adapter) (less likely)

Try option #1 - use JRE 1.6 and Java compiler level 1.6.
Follow the instructions in the answer.