# Worklight Studio and Local Development, sometimes unable to use Java classes, sometimes the HTML files

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using worklight studio with Eclipse Luna.  And sometimes are Java Adapter code will not run.  In that sense, the Java code we reference is not available in the adapter.

Version:
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1/wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.6.0_18-b07 (en_US)

(We were using Worklight 6.2 studio from the Eclipse Marketplace)

So we might see an error like this when we try to reference the Java code:

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project 
TypeError: Cannot call property getClientIpAddress in object [JavaPackage com.worklight.util.ServerUtils]. It is not a function, it is "object". (MyAdapter-impl.js#63)

Also, sometimes when we make HTML or JavaScript changes in the common directory, those changes aren't reflected.

Basically, is there some kind of Worklight cache that we should clean up.  We delete the war out of the bin directory and try to clean and rebuild but the changes aren't reflected.

Also, sometimes I use the worklight console and deploy apps that way.  I notice that the old version of my application is there.  E.g. when I look at the date, it shows last weeks revision.  Where is that application deployment?  Can I just delete the old revision in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [ERROR ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure
>   [project TypeError: Cannot call property getClientIpAddress in object
>   [JavaPackage com.worklight.util.ServerUtils]. It is not a function, it
>   is "object". (MyAdapter-impl.js#63)

You may want to check the following:

- [Worklight adapter It is not a function, it is "object". error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979553/worklight-adapter-it-is-not-a-function-it-is-object-error)
- [ECMA TypeError calling Java class from Worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614742/ecma-typeerror-calling-java-class-from-worklight-adapter)
- [Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826456/ecma-error-typeerror-cannot-call-property)
- [IBM Worklight 6.1 - "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property <function> in object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803265/ibm-worklight-6-1-ecma-error-typeerror-cannot-call-property-function-in-o)
- I also heard that starting a new project solves this. Note that this more relates to Eclipse setup.

> Also, sometimes when we make HTML or JavaScript changes in the common
>   directory, those changes aren't reflected.

Are you working with multiple, different, versions of Studio in your development PC/Mac? Either way, try the following. Note that this has improved in later releases. See if it possible for you to upgrade...

Try deleting the wlBuildResources folder.
See my answer here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed re-generating the iPhone native folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008162/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-re-generating-the-iphone-native-folder/)

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build

Comment: I will try your suggestions

Comment: This seems to work.  I may open a similar question if you don't already know.  I also have a similar problem with the Android project/emulator always getting a direct update message.  I tried deleting the Android project and rebuilding, sometimes that works, sometimes doesnt.