# Error While invoking java code from javascript adapter

Tags: javascript, java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM MobileFirst 7.1 and I am calling java code from Javascript adapter. But, I am getting error while calling adapter. Error is:

```
 {  
   "errors": [  
      "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property main1 in object [JavaPackage com.sample.customcode.SendMail]. It is not a function, it is \"object\". (2016-10- 
05T10:46:40.941Z\/74c15a587d1ce37bbfce9925722acab7b6321aad\/UsingJavaInAdapter-impl.js#19)"  
   ],    
   "info": [  
   ],  
   "isSuccessful": false,  
   "warnings": [  
    ]  
}
```

I have changed Java compiler level to 1.6 as well as default JRE to 1.6 from 1.7.
But still I am facing same error. This code is working in one project in same eclipse workspace. But in another project this not working.

Comment: well, the error message tells you that you are trying to call an object instead of a method. Have you looked into that?

Comment: @Thomas Stets Yes, I have Observed that. And I followed this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826456/ecma-error-typeerror-cannot-call-property). Still I am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also change the Java compiler level for the specific project. Right-click the project and select Properties -> Java Build Path -> Java Compiler.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.